# Number of threads accessing a shared resource

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java interview I was asked 'In multithreading, what should be done so that a shared resource can be accessed by at the most 4 threads ?'
Does anybody know this. Thanks

Comment: The point of this kind of question is not that you give a specific right answer but that you demonstrate that you can discuss the issue intelligently.

Comment: @helloworld I'm not sure he has answered yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean 4 threads concurrently? Or 4 threads total?

If it is the first option (the latter sounds pointless to me) you can use a Semaphore (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Something like

```
public class YourResource {
   private static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_THREADS = 4;

   private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_THREADS ); 

   public void doSomethingWithYourResource() {
      semaphore.acquire();
      try {
         // Code accessed by 4 concurrent threads, tops
      } finally {
         semaphore.release();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, like @Karibasappa-g-c and others mentioned before you can design your application in a way that only four threads access the resource in question, so there won't be any kind of locking needed. 

I guess the question is pretty vague in this matter, so I am offering a different (more pessimistic) solution.

Comment: @Claudio..Thanks for the solution. I think semaphore.acquire() has nothing to do with synchronization. Please correct me if i am wrong. And one more question regarding this solution. Suppose 4 threads are accessing the shared resource(i.e all 4 permits are gone) and new 5th thread calls doSomethingWithYourResource(), then what happens, i mean what is returned then?

Comment: It just blocks until a permit is released (or until the thread is interrumpted). Check the acquire documentation in the Javadoc, it is pretty detailed in that matter. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()

Comment: @Claudio...Thanks for the link. On a different note could u please tell me why wait() should always be called in a loop and not in 'if'. I searched for it but didn't get a good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I encourage you to make a question about this (if there isn't one already). It happens mostly because of two reasons: (1.) threads waiting over a monitor can have an spourious wake-up (that means, can wake up without no reason) and (2.) somebody can call notifyAll instead of notify, so other threads might wake up and take the resource before you can acquire it turning the condition to sleep true again (whatever that condition might be), so you need to check again before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

create 4 threads max using thread pool executor.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             Task task = new Task(someParam, someParam);
            executor.execute(task);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
```

where task is some class which has shared resource.

and to protect shared resource from concurrent modification,synchronize the piece of shared resource.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but it probably is not what the interviewer was looking for.  I bet the intended question is more like,  Suppose you were writing a library that was called by some client program.  The client creates the threads, and you have no control over how many it creates.  How do you limit the number of client threads that are allowed to access a particular library object at the same time?  The expected answer probaby is a data structure invented by a famous computer scientist whose name contains three consecutive alphabet letters in a row.

Comment: @jameslarge : i am happy to see your answer instead of betting about question..please edit the question if you are very sure about the interviewer view and let the community answers easily by understanding question clearly...

Answer (score 0):

I am not considered neither a java expert nor a multithreading expert but I know for example that you can you use factory methods like `newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)` that specifically state that

> At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing
>   tasks.

My main intuition though is that, as @David Schwartz mentioned it was a question just to pick the subject and deploy your thoughts.